# java 7 error: Unable to load native library: ld.so.1: java: fatal: libscf.so.1: open failed: No such file or directory

Tags: java, solaris

I need to run java 7 in a solaris 5.9 sparc 64 bits, but when I run it, I get next error:

```
$java -version

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: ld.so.1: java: fatal: libscf.so.1: open failed: No such file or directory
```

It's same problem either to 32 or to 64 bits jdk-7.

Only for reference, java 6 in same machine doesn't have any problem, but my requirement is with java 7.

Comparing libraries between java 6 and java 7:

-Java 6:

```
$ ldd java

    libthread.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/lwp/libthread.so.1
    libjli.so =>     /myhome/SDK/jdk/bin/../jre/lib/sparc/jli/libjli.so
    libdl.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/libdl.so.1
    libc.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/libc.so.1
    /usr/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-480R/lib/libc_psr.so.1
```

$-Java 7:

```
$ ldd java

    libthread.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/lwp/libthread.so.1
    libjli.so =>     /myhome/jdk7/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/../jre/lib/sparc/jli/libjli.so
    libdl.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/libdl.so.1
    libc.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/libc.so.1
    /usr/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-480R/lib/libc_psr.so.1
```

The only difference is libjli.so. I tried to replace using the version of java 6, but I get a new error.

So, anybody has an idea about libscf.so.1  problem? or how can I get that library?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libscf is part of the Service Management Facility (SMF), part of Solaris 10 and above only.  Presumably the package you downloaded explicitly doesn't support something as old as Solaris 9.

The system requirements here:
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/solaris/solaris-jdk.html

Explicitly state that you must be running Solaris 10 update 9 or newer.

The only way to get libscf would be to upgrade to a much more recentversion of Solaris -- something that's probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: You're right, libscf is included in SUNWcslr package and I didn't find it available for Solaris 9. Java 7 is not supported for Solaris 9 as is indicated in your link. I have to upgrade to Solaris 10. Thanks for your answer richlowe.